# WordPress site showing company name twice

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that is showing the company name twice on every page.

I have looked at

- Custom Theme
- Page Edit
- Page QuickEdit
- General Settings Site Title

and I cannot find where the title is displayed twice.  Any ideas where the double title might be located?

I'm not a WordPress guy.  I'm modifying my post so I can show the header.php code because I don't see the issue.

I looked at the PHP code on the server.  I see the two functions but it appears to be correct according to my reading.

Comment: check functions.php as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally an issue with the theme. Check your themes header.php for one of the following codes:

```
bloginfo('name')
wp_title()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found the problem.